# Binary multiplication on elliptic curves in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, bitwise

I wrote a function in C++ which uses binary multiplication (a form of binary exponentation):

```
public: Point mul(Point p, unsigned int n)
{
    // actually these Points shouldn't have negative coordinates, I use Point(-1, -1) as neutral element on addition (like 0)
    Point r = Point(-1, -1);
    n = mod(n, m);  // the %-operator doesn't return a non-negative integer in every case so I wrote a function
    unsigned int mask = 1 << (sizeof (n) - 1);  // more flexible and platform independent than 1 << 31
    for (; mask; mask >>= 1)
    {
        r = add(r, r);
        if (mask & n)
            r = add(r, p);
    }
    return r;
}
```

**Notes:**

- The function calculates points on elliptic curves over a finite field GF(`m`)
- `Point` is a class I wrote for this. It doesn't do much beside holding two coordinates `x` and `y`
- I just wondered if there is an easier / cleaner solution for binary multiplcation in C++ than I implemented
- The algorithm is like 'double and add' instead of 'square and multiply'

**EDITS:**

This is my `Point` class:

```
class Point
{
    public:
        long long int x, y;

    public: Point(long long int _x, long long int _y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }

    public: void print()
    {
        cout << "(";
        cout << x;
        cout << ", ";
        cout << y;
        cout ")";
    }
};
```

The `mul` function is part of the class `EllipticCurve`:

```
class EllipticCurve
{
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
        unsigned int m;

    public: EllipticCurve(int _a, int_b, unsigned int modul)
    {
        a = _a;
        b = _b;
        m = modul;
    }

    public: Point generate(unsigned long long int x)
    {
        // looks for Points on the curve with the given x coordinate
        // returns the first matching point
    }

    public: Point add(Point p, Point q)
    {
        // complex addition function with if-else trees
        // the function code is not needed for this question
    }

    public: Point mul(Point p, unsigned int n)
    {
        // see above
    }
};
```

Please remember that this question is about the `mul` function, not the rest of the code. I inserted it only for a better understanding.

Comment: @TobySpeight sorry, that wasmy mistake. Of course I used C++ for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>     n = mod(n, m);  // the %-operator doesn't return a non-negative integer in every case so I wrote a function
> ```

I would find a comment explaining `m` more useful than a comment explaining why you made a `mod` function, because everyone ends up writing a `mod` function which behaves sensibly.

I don't know much about elliptic curves, but I have worked with finite fields. Are you *sure* it makes sense to take `n mod m` as though they were integers? The only makes sense to me if `m` is also the characteristic (i.e. if it's a field of prime order).

---

> ```
>     unsigned int mask = 1 << (sizeof (n) - 1);  // more flexible and platform independent than 1 << 31
>     for (; mask; mask >>= 1)
> ```

Why loop down? If you loop up then you get the platform-independence for free, and also you loop fewer times when `n` is small. Obviously the loop invariant would change, but it would be closer to school long multiplication and so might also be more maintainable.

```
    for (; n; n >>= 1)
    {
        if (n & 1)
            r = add(r, p);
        p = add(p, p);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response. yes, it is a field of prime order, `m` is prime. And I'm not sure about if looping up still gives the correct results - I mean that would calculate e.g. `p * 0b110101` instead of `p * 0b101011` if you read the binary digits from rigth to left instead of left to right. wouldn't it?

Comment: and you're right, the use of `mod()` isn't necessary anoymore since I use `unsigned int`. I still need this function in other code parts though.

Comment: @Aemyl, if you change the direction of the loop you'll have to change the body as well, but the result will be very similar to the way you do long multiplication.

Comment: Oh, OK. That seems logic. However, I have no idea how to change the body correctly :/

Answer (score 3):

Just a one liner. The field `public:` and its counterparts define a section. So everything after `public:` is public until `protected`/`private` come up. So there is no need to put it before every function.

Answer (score 3):

#### Bug in mask

Your function doesn't actually do the right thing because of this line:

> ```
> unsigned int mask = 1 << (sizeof (n) - 1);
> ```

On a 32-bit system, you wanted `mask` to be `1 << 31` but what you actually got was `1 << 3` because `sizeof(unsigned int)` is 4.  The correct way would be:

```
unsigned int mask = 1 << (sizeof(n) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
```

because `sizeof` returns a number of bytes and `CHAR_BIT` is defined to be the number of bits per byte.

Of course, if you used the loop Peter Taylor suggested, you wouldn't even need `mask`.

Comment: you're right, I forgot that `sizeof` returns the bytesize instead of the bitsize. Thanks a lot!